# Checking if a part of a text field if is contained in an array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an array of search terms(userSearchTerms) that I want to filter in the Users collection(users = _id + name, ex: Bill Gates, Paul Allen, Satya Nadella).

```
userSearchTerms = string[] {"Bil", "Pau", "Saty"};
```

In mongodb, I managed to query like this:

```
db.users.find({ name: { $in: [ /Bil/i, /Pau/i, /Saty/i ] } })
```

But I'm not able to achieve this with the C# driver(currently using v2.4.4):

```
filter.Where(u => userSearchTerms.Any(st => u.Name.Contains(st)));
```

But I get this ex: *ArgumentException: 'Unsupported filter: Any(value(System.String[]).Where({document}{Name}.Contains({document}))).'*

**Q:** Is there any way that I can achieve this with the C# driver?

Comment: The In() *FilterDefinition* method doesn't have a *BsonRegularExpression* paramter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try merging all of your search terms into a single regex and evaluating without using `$in`:

```
// Produces a regex like: (Bil|Pau|Saty)
string regex = $"^({string.Join("|", userSearchTerms)})";

var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<User>()
    .Regex(u => u.Name, new BsonRegularExpression(regex, "i"));

var users = collection.Find(filter).ToEnumerable();
```

Comment: Yeah but would the query be optimized to use a configured index in that case? Not with case insensitivity, I know.  But with case sensitivity?